# How to filter a backbone collection and render the results

Tags: backbone.js

Total newbie to Backbone so apologize if this is a simple question.

I am have successfully loaded a collection and rendered the view. However I have a dropdown with A tags that I would like to use the filter the data displayed. I'm trying to set an event listener in my VIEW and then trigger a function within the view to filter the results and re-render the view.

Here's my code:

```
IBA.NewsModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
IBA.NewsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: IBA.NewsModel,
    url: "/news/api"
});
IBA.NewsView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#main',
  template: _.template($("#news-article").html()),

  events: {
    "change .dropdown-item": "filterNews"
  },

  initialize: function () {
    this.collection = new IBA.NewsCollection();
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
    this.collection.fetch({
      success: function() {
        console.log("JSON file load was successful");
        view.render();
      },
      error: function(){
        console.log('There was some error in loading and processing the JSON file');
      }
    });
  },

  render: function () {
      this.$el.html(this.template({ 
        articles: this.collection.toJSON() 
      })
    );
    return this;
  },

  filterNews: function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var items = this.collection.where({cat_name: "interviews"});
    console.log(items);
    this.$el.html(this.template({articles: this.items.toJSON()}));
  }
});

var view = new IBA.NewsView();
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do it would be to reset the actual collection with the filtered results:

```js
IBA.NewsModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
IBA.NewsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: IBA.NewsModel,
  url: "/news/api"
});
IBA.NewsView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#main',
  template: _.template($("#news-article").html()),

  events: {
    "change .dropdown-item": "filterNews"
  },

  initialize: function() {
    this.collection = new IBA.NewsCollection();
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
    this.fetchNews();
  },
  fetchNews: function() {
    var view = this;
    this.collection.fetch({
      success: function() {
        console.log("JSON file load was successful");
        view.render();
      },
      error: function() {
        console.log('There was some error in loading and processing the JSON file');
      }
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template({
      articles: this.collection.toJSON()
    }));
    return this;
  },

  filterNews: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.collection.reset(this.collection.where({
      cat_name: "interviews"
    }));
  }
});

var view = new IBA.NewsView();
```

---

When you want to go back to original data, fetch it again using the `fetchNews()` method.

You also had a syntax error that `view` was not defined in your `initialize`

Comment: Thanks TJ. That solution works great. However what approach would you suggest if I didn't want to reload the news each time? I have several filter categories and I presume with this approach I would have to reload the data each time. Can I presort the collection and assign it to an object for each category and then render that?

Comment: Also for some reason the "click" event on .dropdown-item doesn't seem to be getting attached. It's a Twitter Bootstrap component and I guess the TB JS is over riding the click event. Do you know how I could get around this?

Comment: I just worked through the "click" event not being fired and it appears that unless the DOM is rendered through Backbone _template function then it isn't aware of the element and hence isn't registering the event. Is this standard or some kind of issue? Is there a work around for this?